# WPF application is still running in background even after uninstall

Tags: wpf, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have a WPF app and an installer created using Setup Project in Visual Studio. The APP is having a tray icon and works based on that.
When I tried to uninstall the application folder gets uninstalled but the instance of the app is still running.

Is there a way I can close my app when it's uninstalled?.. Please help

Comment: kindly give us some [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with.

Answer (score 0):

When the program is uninstalled,you can use [System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0)  static method  to check if the process exists.if exist,close it.

such as

```
 var notepad = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
 if (notepad.Length > 0)
     notepad[0].Kill();
```

Comment: Is there any event fired when the application is uninstalled?

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio's setup project. I used Install Shield to make installation packages. It can perform some operations during installation, such as checking whether the program is running when uninstalling, opening the program after the installation is complete, and so on. You can also use [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2022), [nsis](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/) and similar tools to make installation packages.

Comment: Ohk. Thank you @Sync for the information.